Validate expire time and signing key algorithm
I have the following code used to decode and verify JWT token:
public class JwtTokenDecoder implements JwtDecoder {

    private String secretKey = '123456789';

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {

        JwtParser build = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(getSigningKey()).build();
        io.jsonwebtoken.Jwt<?, ?> parse = build.parse(token);
        Map<String, Object> claims = JsonHelper.jsonMapper().convertValue(parse.getPayload(), new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        claims.put("iat", Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) claims.get("iat")));
        claims.put("exp", Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) claims.get("exp")));
        return Jwt.withTokenValue(token)
                .headers((val) -> val.putAll(parse.getHeader()))
                .claims((val) -> val.putAll(claims))
                .build();
    }

    private SecretKey getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}

How I can verify also expire based on minimum acceptable value? For example I want to verify that the token is not older than 30 days for example and set manually the algorithm type value.

Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) claims.get("exp")).isAfter(Instant.now().minus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS)); ?

Two main things i would say are missing are: mentioning the encryption algorithm for singing (in code below i used SHA256), the token life validity needed some refreshin, i added the method validateTokenAge.
You can try the code below:
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JwtTokenDecoder implements JwtDecoder {

    private String secretKey = "123456789";
    private static final SignatureAlgorithm EXPECTED_ALGORITHM = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256; // Example: Use HS256
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
        // Setup JwtParser with signature verification using the expected algorithm
        JwtParser parser = Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSigningKey())
            .requireAlgorithm(EXPECTED_ALGORITHM) // Require the token to be signed with HS256
            .build();

        // Parse the JWT
        Jws<Claims> jws = parser.parseClaimsJws(token);
        Map<String, Object> claimsMap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(jws.getBody(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

        // Convert iat and exp to Instant
        convertEpochToInstant(claimsMap);

        // Validate the token expiration against your business rule
        validateTokenAge(jws.getBody());

        return Jwt.withTokenValue(token)
                  .headers(headers -> headers.putAll(jws.getHeader()))
                  .claims(claims -> claims.putAll(claimsMap))
                  .build();
    }

    private void convertEpochToInstant(Map<String, Object> claims) {
        claims.put("iat", Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) claims.get("iat")));
        claims.put("exp", Instant.ofEpochSecond((long) claims.get("exp")));
    }

    private void validateTokenAge(Claims claims) throws JwtException {
        Instant issueTime = claims.getIssuedAt().toInstant();
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Instant thirtyDaysAgo = now.minusDays(30);

        if (issueTime.isBefore(thirtyDaysAgo)) {
            throw new JwtException("Token is older than 30 days");
        }
        
        if (claims.getExpiration().toInstant().isBefore(now)) {
            throw new JwtException("Token has expired");
        }
    }

    private SecretKey getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}

